# Array arguments to ifs are of different size

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am getting at error that 'Array arguments to ifs are of different size',and this errors shows up after 1000 rows. I need this formula to autofill, so it is added in the top row. Using VLOOKUP to match two sheets data and only display value from 'Conv' sheet only if column J contains "Demo Request". The number of rows in sheets in different, so I am not sure how to make it work.

Here's the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(row(J:J)=1,"Demo Request",IF(ISBLANK(I:I),"",IFERROR(IF('Conv'!F:F="Demo Request",VLOOKUP(I:I,'Conv'!A:G,7,FALSE),0),0))))
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
={"Demo Request"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2:I="",,
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I2:I, {FILTER('Ads Conv'!A:G, 
 TRIM('Ads Conv'!F:F)="Demo Request")}, 7, 0), 0)))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This returns 'False' in all rows, whereas I need it to populate values from the 'Conv' sheet column number 7.

Comment: Here a link to the sheet with placeholder data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-sW1C8lDnHc3CJQJY4Xr27Dpg3ASfBn6i0N-3dovsrs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EJ2iVWf_41_qhNLQ-XVxO5DlwYgyP14RjmMXkGUmuec/edit#gid=1056768622

Comment: This solution does total column 7 so that's awesome, but I need it total only if column F in 'Conv' sheet is "Demo Request".  thanks for the help! btw

Comment: Hi! I have a follow up questions on this - current formula returns the first instance when data matches. Is there a way for it to SUM the Demo Request Column?For example, Demo Request in Ads tab records 3, but there are 3 additional conversions Here's a new sheet with mockup data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LTU7zGb8tIBRRrBN48hfm6NSeOK261beJO-WtQ1ReW0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try: `={"Demo Request"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2:I="",,
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I2:I, {QUERY({TRIM('Ads Conv'!A:F), 'Ads Conv'!G:G}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col7) where Col6='Demo Request' group by Col1 label sum(Col7)''", 0)}, 2, 0), 0)))}`